# translate network option in docker run to docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like to translate the following docker command to a docker-compose file:

```
docker run -d  --restart=always -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --net shinyproxy-net -p 8080:8080 imshinyproxy
```

This is the `docker-compose.yml` that I wrote:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  shinyproxy:
    image: imshinyproxy
    container_name: imshinyproxy
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=65537
      - TZ=america/new_york
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - shinyproxy-net
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Alas, when I try to run `docker-compose up` I get the following error:

```
$ docker-compose up
ERROR: Service "shinyproxy" uses an undefined network "shinyproxy-net"
```

I know the network exist:

```
$ sudo docker network create shinyproxy-net
Error response from daemon: network with name shinyproxy-net already exists
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must declare an `external` network in the `networks` section of your `docker-compose.yml` :

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  shinyproxy:
    [...]
    networks:
      - shinyproxy-net

networks:
  shinyproxy-net:
    external:
      name: shinyproxy-net
```

`networks.shinyproxy-net.external.name` should correspond to the name of your previously created network.